# Random image - corresponding text

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to display text that corresponds to random image in another part of an email? My code so far:

```
VAR @random, @num1, @num3
SET @num1 = 1 
SET @num3 = 3 


SET @random = random(@num1, @num3) 
]%% 

%%[IF @random == "1" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 1 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152367" src="Image 1 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="2" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152368" src="Image 2 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="3" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152366" src="Image 3 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Couldnt find what i needed here - unless i missed something [Showing random image in email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239605/showing-random-image-in-email)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are those texts stored and how are they linked to images?

Comment: They are not stored in a DE they are just the names of the people in the photos. So when image X is displayed in email display person name X etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display text under the image:

```
%%[IF @random == "1" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 1 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152367" src="Image 1 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

<p>Some random text related to image 1</p>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="2" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152368" src="Image 2 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

<p>Some random text related to image 2</p>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="3" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152366" src="Image 3 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

<p>Some random text related to image 3</p>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

If you need to display the text in a completely different place, just add it to the main script:

```
%%[
VAR @random, @num1, @num3, @text
SET @num1 = 1 
SET @num3 = 3 
    
SET @random = random(@num1, @num3) 

IF @random == "1" THEN
   set @text = "some text 1"
ELSEIF @random =="2" THEN 
   set @text = "some text 2"
ELSEIF @random =="3" THEN 
   set @text = "some text 3"
ENDIF

]%% %%[IF @random == "1" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 1 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152367" src="Image 1 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="2" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152368" src="Image 2 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ELSEIF @random =="3" THEN ]%% 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center">
<a href="Image Link 2 here" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://"> <img data-assetid="152366" src="Image 3 URL here" alt="" height="390" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 390px; width: 700px; border: 0px;"></a></td></tr></table>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

And include `%%=v(@text)=%%` anywhere where this text should be displayed.

Comment: I tried to set the image and text like in the second one but then the image doesn't display anymore.

Comment: You need to include the whole script - I just included the first block in my second example. So after that you need to include that whole party with html where you link images

Comment: I updated my answer ^^

Comment: OK! - I see that now, I am still learning this so it took me a second - thank you for the update.

Comment: if the code fails will it just display blank or can I add in a fall back image/text somehow?

Comment: You can add a fallback by adding an ELSE section to both your statements

Answer (score 2):

What I might do to account for potential growth of random information, is to store all the information inside of a data extension.

I would have the following in the DE:

```
ID   |   ImageURL   |   Text
---------------------------------
1    | myImageURL1  |  Some Text1
2    | myImageURL2  |  Some Text2
```

Where ID is the primary key of the DE. This would store all the dynamic info you want associated together, so you can add/remove fields as needed.

Then inside the email, I would do the same Random function, but I would also do a LookupRows() and then set the values via ROW() and Field().

See below:

**First**, you need to get the size of the DE for the `@max` value using DataExtensionRowCount function:

```
SET @min = 1
SET @max = DataExtensionRowCount('myDE')
```

This will set the total number of rows in the DE to the max for the random function.

**Second**, you will gather the random number via AMPScript:

```
SET @random = Random(@min,@max)
```

This will grab a random number between 1 and the row count of your content DE. For the sake of this example, let's say the number is 3.

**Next**, now that we have the random number, what do we do? We then do a LookupRows() to retrieve the row from your DE.

```
SET @randRS = LookupRows('myDE',"ID",@random)
```

**Finally**, this will then return a rowset of the identified record. You can then use Row() and Field() to gather the info you need.

```
SET @row = Row(@randRS,1)
SET @image = Field(@row,"ImageURL")
SET @text = Field(@row,"Text")
```

You then just put the image/text as variable calls. Like so:

```
<img src="%%=v(@image)=%%" />
<p>%%=v(@text)=%%</p>
```

no need to use any if statements, etc.

Comment: I wanted users to be able to manage this and unfortunately they are not allowed permissions to upload to DE's so this wasn't an option for us - I will bear in mind for other projects and great to read for my learning too!